# SeekTo initially in Android's Mediaplayer makes mediaplayer not work

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-mediaplayer

This is the method where I create my Mediaplayer and set it's source, but directly after I call seekTo it does't play anymore (If I give it some time-depends on the audio, it worksm--> Conclusion after debug).

```
public void makeAudio(boolean isInit){
    try{
        if(!isInit){
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        }
        soundSource = episode.getAudio();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(soundSource);
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();


        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                soundLength = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
                seekBar.setMax(soundLength/1000);
               mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);//the problem I guess
            }
        });

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It shows me this error message:

```
E/MediaPlayerNative: Attempt to perform seekTo in wrong state: mPlayer=0x706c23ebc0, mCurrentState=0
```

I would like to have any suggestion about this, because I want to make my mediaplayer go to the progress value(I get it from my intent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use ExoPlayer, it is an improved version of MediaPlayer and addListener works better for online audio.

You have to add listener until it is prepared and only then you can get the duration:

```
exoPlayer.addListener(new Player.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
                    if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_READY) {
                        long realDurationMillis = exoPlayer.getDuration();
                        seekBar.setMax((int)realDurationMillis/1000);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }

                    if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_ENDED){
                        performEndExoPlayer();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Here is an example you can have a look https://developer.android.com/codelabs/exoplayer-intro#5